# Что за 3 сектор на диске?

Tags: ос

Просто для галочки хочу спросить что за 3 сектор на диске (программа victoria)
И что на нём должно храниться, меня смутило надпись "a r t i t i o n".
Теперь не только думаю что это такое) но ещё и смотрю 2 сектор диска в котором похожее содержимое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главный вопрос: почему?.

Comment: partition, ну почитайте про разделы диска (партиции)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почему вас смутило именно artition, если полная надпись явно "Basic data partition". Которая очень похожа на название раздела диска. А раз там название, то скорее всего у вас используется таблица разделов GPT. Собственно с этого надо начинать, с определения системы разбиения диска. И еще с того, 3 сектор, это какой, третий на диске или 4й (если нумерация с 0). А для этого надо смотреть таблицу разделов в 0 секторе (ну или 1 если с него нумерация у вас в программе). В этом секторе лежит MBR, а в ней таблица разделов старого образца. Если в ней один раздел с типом 0xEE, то имеем дело с разбиением GPT. А значит смотрим [информацию по структуре GPT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_GUID). Там указано что в первых секторах после MBR идет несколько секторов с информацией о разделах, каждая запись которых начинается с GUID типа раздела, за которым идет другая информация, включая имя раздела. В вашем случае сектор начинается на A2 A0 D0 EB, что по таблице из википедии сразу наводит на EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 ("Основной раздел данных"), что так же соответствует названию на английском языке, записанную далее в секторе. Таким образом можно утверждать, что в этом секторе у вас записи данных о разделах.